# Page preview is shown, updating page gives 404 error

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, 404-error, apache

I can add new pages and preview them, but once I upload them I get a 404 "Not found" error. I thought it's a problem with my permalinks, so I followed some tutorials to fix this like http://www.felfelworld.com/2013/02/12/page-not-found-permalink-wordpress/. Had the same settings, but I couldn't find the `httpd.conf` file. I tried testing the configuration or finding it with `apachectl configtest` and `find httpd.conf`. Here's my `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

It's in the root folder of my webiste with the permissions 644.
This is what's happening when uploading a new page (preview > update > error):

[image: Preview]

---

[image: 404 error]

If I go back to the editor and click preview again I get the same error.

**Edit:** I was looking  for other tutorials and figured the files would have the wrong permissions. So I did a bit of testing and changed the permissions of `.htaccess`, went to Permalinks and saw that it's not writable anymore. I changed the permissions again, switched from "Post name" to "Plain" (default) and it works. But leaving it like this basically doesn't allow me to use Permalinks anymore.

Comment: So have you tried switching to a default theme and disabling all plugins?

Comment: The theme I am using is a default theme. I have also tried deactivating all plugins, not working. When disabling the plugins I can't even preview the page anymore

Comment: I was thinking that the Apache's rewrite module may be disabled.. but I'm guessing you already checked that and confirmed it's enabled? Does the error show up when viewing all pages (single posts, category archives, etc.) that have permalinks, or only specific pages? Have you checked the error logs - is there anything that might be relevant to the error `404`?

Comment: Try also clearing your browser's cache - and if enabled, your site's cache.

Comment: The rewrite module is enabled. The error shows up for all kinds of pages. I couldn't check the error log because it was disabled on the wp_config.php file and cleaned the cache. I changed the permissions to my files and .htaccess, then went to permalinks and it said that the file is not writable. I gave the file other permissions, then went back to permalinks and changed them from post name to plain. With that I can preview and upload every page but it means that it'll have to stay this way in order to work, which is not what I had in mind. I'd basically mean I can't use the permalinks :/

Comment: How about, 1) Rename the existing `.htaccess` file to `htaccess.old` (or some other name) and 2) Change the permalink structure back to "Post name", without creating a `.htaccess` file.

Comment: The same - I can preview, uploading gives the error. For already existing pages I'm getting the error when previewing them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93099/discussion-between-rin-and-sally-cj).

Comment: Try closing your IF module, just before the # End Wordpress you should have a line with "</IfModule>"